# Change SID of USER DBO in SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sid

I am not able to create a USER with name PUBLISH_ADMIN in a  user Database.

In Master Database, LOGIN PUBLISH_ADMIN has SID = 0x010600000000006400000000000000002532749BDD5C974C9BA8EF44CFA5.

In User Database same SID[0x010600000000006400000000000000002532749BDD5C974C9BA8EF44CFA5] belongs to USER DBO.

Due to this I am not able to create user **PUBLISH_ADMIN** which should map to LOGIN **PUBLISH_ADMIN**.

Is there any way to change the SID of the USER DBO in the User DB ?  So the remap the user **PUBLISH_ADMIN** to login **PUBLISH_ADMIN**.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you used the `LOGIN` `PUBLISH_ADMIN` to `CREATE` the database. When a `LOGIN` creates a database it is automatically mapped to the `USER` `dbo`. There is no need to create it its own user, as it already have one. If you don't want to `LOGIN` to automatically be mapped to the `USER` `dbo`, then don't use that `LOGIN` to `CREATE` the database. :)

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept(mark) or vote it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can not change the user sid for now.

As Larnu said in comment:

You used the LOGIN `PUBLISH_ADMIN` to create the database. When a LOGIN creates a database it is automatically mapped to the USER `dbo`. There is no need to create it its own user, as it already have one.

In a word, the default user name of admin account login `PUBLISH_ADMIN`:

1. In master, username is same with login name "`PUBLISH_ADMIN`" .
2. In user database, default user name will be "DBO".

For example, you can test this with bellow code:

```
USE MASTER
SELECT name as username, sid AS usersid FROM sys.database_principals WHERE sid=SUSER_SID()

USE User Database
SELECT name as username, sid AS usersid FROM sys.database_principals WHERE sid=SUSER_SID()
```

Reference: [SUSER_SID (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can alter the user name same with login name "PUBLISH_ADMIN":

```
USE USER-DATABASER
ALTER USER DBO WITH NAME = PUBLISH_ADMIN;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon, Thanks for clarifying.I am not able to alter the user dbo with Publish_Admin. Error Message : Cannot alter the user 'DBO'.

Comment: Did you alter it in user database?